# Active Navbar in NextJS

Tags: next.js

I am trying to add a style to active Navbar on NextJs. i have tried to several
I imported `useRouter()` from `next/navigation`

I seems like this is outdated in a way

```
 
 <li className='font-medium py-1 my-2' ><Link href="/dashboard/admission/offer" className={`${router.pathname === "/dashboard/admission/offer" ? 'bg-gray-100 text-purple-800' : ""}  text-sm py-2.5 px-3 flex gap-4 items-center rounded`}> <MdOutlineVerifiedUser className='text-xl'/> Offer Letter</Link> </li>
 <li className='py-1 my-3 bg-white'><Link href="/dashboard/admission/state" className={`${router.pathname === "/dashboard/admission/state" ? 'bg-gray-100 text-purple-800' : ""}  text-sm py-2.5 px-3 flex gap-4 items-center rounded`} ><TbBrandReactNative />State of Origin</Link></li>
 <li className='py-1 my-3 bg-white'> <Link href="/dashboard/admission/conduct" className={`${router.asPath === "/dashboard/admission/conduct" ? 'bg-gray-100 text-purple-800' : ""}  text-sm py-2.5 px-3 flex gap-4 items-center rounded`}> <GoCodeOfConduct />Code  Conduct</Link>  </li>
 <li className='py-1 my-3 bg-white'><Link href="/dashboard/admission/medical"  className={`${router.pathname === "/dashboard/admission/medical" ? 'bg-gray-100 text-purple-800' : ""}  text-sm py-2.5 px-3 flex gap-4 items-center rounded`}><TbFileReport /> Medical Report</Link></li>
```

I get the `Property 'asPath' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance'.`

also get this `Property 'pathname' does not exist on type 'AppRouterInstance'`

Answer (score 0):

There are ***two*** `useRouter` hooks, one is the ["app"](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router) hook, imported from `next/navigation`, that returns an AppRouter and is intended to be used client-side, e.g. with the `"use client"` directive, while the other is the ["pages"](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router) hook, imported from `next/router`, and used server-side.

It's this latter "pages" `useRouter` that returns a PageRouter `router` with `asPath` and `pathname` properties.

[Router object](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router#router-object)

Update the code to import the pages router hook.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
```

```js
const router = useRouter(); // PageRouter

...

// router.pathname
// router.asPath
```